# Is there a word for days of mental clarity?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

You hear about these a lot in people with Alzheimers. This can also happen to normal people when they eat right and get a good night's sleep and feel very clear headed.

I am looking for a more formal word, as opposed to informal (e.g. A-game days would be informal)

Is there a term, preferably one word, that describes this phenomenon?

Comment: not one word, but I usually use the phrase "in the zone".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They have [lucid](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lucid) days.

> Showing or having the ability to think clearly, especially in intervals between periods of confusion or insanity:

but it's not usually applied to people whose mental processes are normal all the time.

Example:

> *"We have heard from several people that close relatives with Alzheimer's disease became amazingly lucid for short periods of time after receiving narcotic pain relievers."*

More examples:

- [When Alzheimer's Patients Make Perfect Sense: Those Stunning Moments of Total Lucidity](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/marie-marley/alzheimers_b_1511450.html)
- [Alzheimer's Symptom: Has sudden lucid moments](https://www.caring.com/symptoms/alzheimers-symptoms/has-sudden-lucid-moments)
- [Why Do Alzheimer's Patients Have Lucid Moments?](http://www.alzheimersreadingroom.com/2011/10/why-do-alzheimers-patients-have-lucid.html)